# How to position an image, when there are multiple images in the html document

Tags: css, html, css-position, positioning, cloud9-ide

Ok so I am creating a website, and on one of my pages there are several images, as you can see from the code below they all have the img tag. I know you need to make the different images unique so that they don't all follow the same css tags, but I am struggling to make mine work, as they all follow the "img" css tag, and i can't resolve the issue. Also for some reason the image has ended up in the footer, and even without any css it still stays there.

HTML code

```
<h4>Download CV</h4>
      ˚<p> If you want to see my full resume please click the link below and enjoy!</p>
        <a download="Curriculum Vitae RWP.docx" href="../Curriculum Vitae RWP.docx" title="R**** A*** CV">
        <div class ="imagelist" id = "imagelist" > 
        <img class="imagelist" alt="CV" src="../Images/cv.png" width ="150" height="150" />
        </a>
```

CSS Code

```
imagelist{
margin-left:500px;
}

img{
float:none;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: `margin-left:500px` is a big red flag you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: no that was just a test to see if anything changed, which in my case didn't

Comment: Then you really need to demo the problem. Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to close your div.imagelist

```
<h4>Download CV</h4>
<p> If you want to see my full resume please click the link below and enjoy!</p>
<a download="Curriculum Vitae RWP.docx" href="../Curriculum Vitae RWP.docx" title="R**** A*** CV">
  <div class ="imagelist" id = "imagelist" > 
    <img class="imagelist" alt="CV" src="../Images/cv.png" width ="150" height="150" />
  </div>
</a>
```

Also, using the same class on your img as on it's parent will not end up great with your styling. I recommend removing the class from the **img** tag and target the image inside your imagelist with the following css:

```
.imagelist img {}
```

For the current css, you forgot to put a dot in front of **imagelist**

Hope this helps you a bit to keep you ongoing.